# What is the difference between "nudge" and "push"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, verbs, formality

> I am trying to nudge them towards a practical solution.

What does *nudge* imply here? Can't we just use something like *push*?
Is the word outdated or still in use?

I'm not trying to avoid using *nudge* as such, just don't know if it is a suitable word to use in an academic context.

Comment: Does your dictionary just list them as the same?

Comment: Nope, but i don't know if it is proper to use this word or not? That's why we ask questions.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. As it stands, this question is incomplete. Please edit the question to show your research; it will also be helpful to provide context to the question, such as why you want to avoid saying "nudge".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the context of ***nudge*** vs. ***push***, ***"push"*** would be considered much more aggressive, violent or maybe just assertive.

a ***"nudge"*** is gentle

> **Example**: If your spouse is snoring you can do the following:
>
> ***"nudge"*** them, where, if you're lucky, they'll roll over without waking up, maybe stop snoring
>
> or
>
> you can ***"push"*** them out of the bed, they'll fall on the floor,
>   wake up, stop snoring

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any information about the etymology? Isn't it outdated?

Comment: I did find etymology on etymonline.com.  The word seems to date back to the 1600's, of dutch origin and may have a couple of different sources, throughout history, including relation to the word "nudnik".  As far as being antiquated, I'd say not really - there's even an online dating site called "alittlenudge.com" :-)

Comment: If you have to use it in a academical context, would you suggest it? Or is there a better replacement? Btw, thanks for your kindness and time.

Comment: For a formal document, I would try one of the many synonyms for the definition of "nudge", to *egg on*: encourage, exhort, goad, press, prod, prompt.  Other related words: drive, propel, spur, stimulate; hurry, hustle, push, rush; adjure, beseech, implore, importune; blandish, cajole, coax, soft-soap, wheedle; high-pressure, nag, needle, pressure; foment, incite, instigate, provoke, stir (up)

Comment: Wow, you lost me :D. i really appreciate your help. I am currently out of vote, i'll vote up soon.

Comment: Sorry Benyamin!  Top 3 nudge replacements that are equally subtle but not too informal: encourage, prompt, press (in my opinion!)  It's been a pleasure to help!

Comment: Give me a hug!:p

Comment: Regarding replacements, those work for the figurative but you might actually mean *a small gentle push* as in, "The picture frame is not quite level can you nudge the left side up about an eighth of an inch?"

Comment: @Jim, I was using the OP's example as a guide for possible synonyms.

Comment: +1 purely for the evocative example! @Benyamin: I don't know why you would think *nudge* is "outdated". Unsurprisingly, it's not so common as *push* (the [697th most common](http://www.englishclub.com/vocabulary/common-words-5000.htm) word in the English language). But it's still a perfectly normal everyday word.

Answer (score 4):

A nudge can be seen as a gentle push, and is often used figuratively, as in as in the book ['Nudge: Improving Decisions About Health, Wealth and Happiness'](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Nudge-Improving-Decisions-Health-Happiness/dp/0141040017/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1358534722&sr=1-1)

The origin of *nudge* is uncertain, but there is, apparently, a Norwegian word *nugge*, meaning 'to push'.

Comment: Awesome, thank you Barrie for that. Do you suggest using it or you have a better verb in mind?

Comment: @Benyamin Hamidekhoo. Semantically related verbs, depending on context, are _dig, jog, prod, shove, poke,prompt, influence, urge, persuade, spur_ and _coax_. No word is better or worse than any other in itself. It derives its value from the company it keeps.